# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while passing a variable in API

Tags: python

i have the below code:

```
from flask import Flask
from kontekst_report_server import kontekst


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<vardate>")
def hello(vardate):
    kontekst(vardate)
    return "Script Completed"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i am passing the variable vardate to the function kontekst as below:

```
def kontekst(vardate):

    # SQLDbObj
    sqlDbObj = DB()

    OPENdata = "select * from ts_data where substr(created_on,1,10)=%s" (vardate)
    opendata = sqlDbObj.query(OPENdata)
```

But when i am accessing this via http://127.0.0.1:5000/2018-09-14, am getting below error:

> OPENdata = "select * from ts_data where substr(created_on,1,10)=%s"
>   (vardate) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

how would i fix this to retrieve data for the passed date?

Comment: You forgot the `%` operator. But that being said it is very unsafe to write such queries.

Comment: Do not do parameter formatting yourself. Probably the `.query(..)` function has a way to "inject" parameters in an SQL-injection safe way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a percent sign between your sql string and `(vardate)`.

Therefore the python interpreter thinks you want to call that string as a function. Change your code to

```
OPENdata = "select * from ts_data where substr(created_on,1,10)=%s" % (vardate)
```

Nowadays, the suggestion for string formatting is [using the `str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```
"select * from ts_data where substr(created_on,1,10)={}".format(vardate)
```

By the way, as stated by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) you should never ever pass your input directly to the database as this makes your application vulnerable to [sql injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

It is highly recommended to use whatever functionallity your library for database connections brings to exscape every user input.

Comment: Noo... don't do string formatting yourself!! This make the system vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Of course, I totally agree with you. But I do not think that this is in the scope of the question.

You can submit your own answer with an example for sql friendly string escaping and you will have my upvote ;)

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to put a *warning* in your answer. Since now the OP (and other users looking at this answer), might think that this is a good/common idea, and thus will make SQL vulnerable software. If you add a warning, you have an upvote :)

Comment: Another, and I believe that a more preferred way would be to use f-strings, i.e.: `f"select * from ts_data where substr(created_on,1,10)={vardate}"`, if we're on Python >= 3.6 of course

Comment: @kalehmann - Thanks a lot for pointing out the error :-). One more thing incase i want to pass the variables as query parameters (such that i can pass more than one) what changes do i need to do in the first script? I searched in net but not getting a clear picture. Would be helpful if you can provide your input.

Comment: @SławomirGórawski thanks for pointing that out, I didn't even knew this yet.

Comment: @SoubhikBanerjee you can just add more `%s` or `{}` to your format string at the positions you want your parameters to be. 
Or even better you take a look a the documentation of the module you use for the database connection and search for the functions they offer for creating query strings. Most likely their functions even include escaping the parameters by default.